# Bootstrap 4 align bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a full-page bootstrap layout, and on the first page I need something aligned to middle & bottom.
There is a background image (first div), and a darker layer on it (second div).

```
<div class="h-100 w-100">
<div class="h-100 w-100 text-center">
    <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <h1 style="color:#000;">something</h1>  
            <a href="">
            www.something.com
            </a>
            <p class="tto_cl">
            <span style="font-size: 1.8rem;">123</span>
            </p>
            <span style="text-transform:uppercase; color:#000; letter-spacing: 4px; font-family: Arial;">456</span><br>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/543r2dcs/2/

They are aligned center perfectly, but I need something to bottom.

I want the 456 to the bottom of the div, but this new flexbox system is unusual to me.

Comment: At the bottom of *which* div? Because that span is at the bottom of it's parent...I suspect your demo does not show the whole problem. Is the container supposed to be full page...because it's not in your demo?

Comment: Ohh...and you can't align everything to the center AND have something aligned to the bottom...flexbox doesn't work that way.

Comment: Bottom of first div.

Comment: Bottom of the page, if it's better. Like a footer.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap has a very handy .align-bottom class. You can read about it [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/)

`<span class="align-bottom">bottom</span>`

Comment: I've tried it before, does not work.

Comment: @nervus hmm, that's weird.. it's worked fine for me before, and it aligns it to the bottom center.

Comment: And I want a pic to the bottom too, not just the text :/

Comment: The `align-bottom` class use the `vertical-align:bottom` property/value, and that will have no effect on flex items.

Comment: You have to break out of Bootstrap4 - it uses CSS's notoriously flawed vertical alignment, hence won't work in DIVs.

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent element `position: relative` then set the poisition for the element you want to be down the bottom to `position: absolute` then set its bottom to 0 `bottom: 0` this will position it to the bottom of its parent container this might also break how you are centering the element so you will have to add `left: 0` and `right: 0`

Comment: The problem is that this is not responsive. Bootstrap really needs to fix this bug. align-bottom should work for nested divs, period. Makes no sense they've ignored this for 4 releases!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be vertically centered, use `my-auto margin y auto`, which brings it to the center

Comment: It is vertically centered. I want the span align to the bottom.