# Bootstrap 4 Cards Same Height and Bottom Justified

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align Bootstrap 4 cards and using `d-flex` along with `align-self-stretch` for the cards themselves. Which is great.

However, I can't figure out how to get the part with the red border to float to the bottom. Any ideas by using Bootstrap 4 [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) only?

[image: bootstrap 4 cards]

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-self-stretch">
    <div class="card shadow-sm mb-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Longer title here that wraps two lines</h5>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <div class="align-self-end border border-danger">
                <p class="text-uppercase mb-0">Donors: 123</p>
                <p class="text-uppercase">Funded: $1,234</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: working on it _ though it would have been easier to have the code for all three cards _ can you add the rest? #JustSaying

Comment: Thanks! The code is the same for all 3 cards, just different char length for `card-title` and `p text-muted` items.

Comment: well nothing seems to be working that I've tried _ In this question (which might be classed as a duplicate of yours?) there's a discussion that achieving vertical alignment within parents needs external CSS _ Check out the bottom answer >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391500/bootstrap-4-align-bottom

Comment: check out another answer here >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719567/css-class-align-self-end-not-working _ there's a solution and explanation as to why `align-self` doesn't work with `card`

Comment: Awesome, that 2nd question worked to solve my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [inputforcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711083/inputforcolor) for help with the solution below, which keeps the cards the same height AND pushes the part I was looking for to the bottom.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-self-stretch">
    <div class="card shadow-sm mb-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Longer title here that wraps two lines</h5>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto border border-danger">
                <p class="text-uppercase mb-0">Donors: 123</p>
                <p class="text-uppercase">Funded: $1,234</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the tag ; ) perhaps you should mention `d-flex` and `flex-column` in the text so that your answer highlights the changes you made _ Makes it more useful for others ; )

Comment: Good idea. Did you want to post a more full answer? I would be happy to accept your answer :)

Comment: Accepted answer would make me an SO reviewer _ but it wasn't really 'my' solution so I'm good thanks _ Pleased we found your answer _ Take Care Dario

Comment: Works great! Here is a slightly simplified codepen to illustrate this https://codepen.io/sgelbart/pen/eYbQJMq?editors=1000